# How to use a promise inside an object literal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

In [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) version 2.0 the [$translate service](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service) no longer returns the actual translation but a promise. I can see that is a good idea because there could be some asynchronous loading going on. But it confuses me how to use the service properly in my case, because I used the $translate service inside an object literal, like this

```
$scope.myDefs = [
      ...
      {
            field: 'supplier',
            displayName: $translate('Supplier'),
            cellTemplate: "<div class=\"ngCellText\">...</div>"
      },
      ...
      {
            field: 'supplierSize',
            displayName: $translate('Size'),
            width: 100,
            cellClass: "center"
      }
      ...
];
```

**Question:** How do I use a promise inside an object literal?

It is supposed to (according to the [documentation](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/03_using-translate-service)) be used like this:

```
$translate('HEADLINE').then(function (headline) {
    $scope.headline = headline;
});
```

Comment: I wish you could "follow" a question on SO without necessarily marking it as a favorite. or... "notify when accepted".  I know there's a super slick way to do this, but it's Sunday evening and my brain won't re-engage properly.  I do like @calebboyd's answer below, but something tells me there's a way to create a custom service to do what you want... which is sorta what he did, just not abstracted to the service layer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd need to have a direct reference. Or a helper function that has closure over the reference. Like:

```
$scope.myDefs = [
    ...
    createArrayObject({
        field: 'supplier',
        displayName: $translate('Supplier'),
        cellTemplate: "<div class=\"ngCellText\">...</div>"        
    }),
    createArrayObject(.....

]
```

and elsewhere

```
function createArrayObject(obj){
    obj.displayName.then(function(data){
       obj.displayName = data;
    });
    return obj;  
}
```

**Update**

as Brian suggested below, Its always a good idea to write generic code you can use all over.

```
var forEach = angular.forEach,
    isFunction = angular.isFunction;

function resolveProperties(obj){
    forEach(obj,function(val,key){
        if(isFunction(val.then)){
            val.then(function(data){
                obj[key] = data;
            });
        }
    });
}
```

So you can use it like...

```
[
    resolveProperties({
        myPropertyToResolve: promiseReturningFunction() 
    }),
    ....   
]
```

Comment: you could just reference the current object literal context inside the "then" with "this".

Comment: myDefs has to be an array, I use it with a 3rd party library, and `this` is undefined...

Comment: oh right, but then there's no benefit of having the function call in the object literal, because you aren't returning anything

Comment: Yeah, that is my problem. Before angular-translate changed their implementation I could just translate the words inside the literal, now I just get a promise back. I don't se an easy way to solve this. Direct references are hard to make because it's an array.

Comment: You can use a closure then to access the reference, see updated answer

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that approach tomorrow

Comment: @calebboyd, I like this approach.  After thinking about it, I'd recommend that you de-couple it a bit, and make it an `$invoke`able service instead.

Answer (score 14):

If you know that there's no asynchronous stuff going on, you can use `$translate.instant()` which behaves exactly like `$translate()` in 1.x.

Answer (score 3):

If you re using ui-grid, solution is to add headerCellFilter: 'translate' to columnsDefs (means myDefs) and displayName must have translation key.

Here is,

```html
$scope.myDefs = [
      {
            field: 'supplier',
            displayName: "Supplier",
            cellTemplate: "<div class=\"ngCellText\">...</div>",
            headerCellFilter: 'translate'
      },
      {
            field: 'supplierSize',
            displayName: "Size",
            width: 100,
            cellClass: "center",
            headerCellFilter: 'translate'
      }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is to loop through your literal and replace all the promises with values. However I don't know what happens if you call then, when a promise has already been resolved.

```
angular.forEach($scope.myDefs, function(element){
   element.displayName.then(function(result){
      element.displayName= result;
   })
})
```